# Animation is not a constructor in ionic

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework

I want to adjust the animation of toastAlert, but it show the error
I use the Animation in @ionic/core, and my ionic version is ionic v5
may be is the version problem, but I don't know how to solve that,
does anyone can help me ?

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: AnimationC is not a constructor
TypeError: AnimationC is not a constructor
```

Here is the `customAlertEnter.ts`

```
import { Animation } from '@ionic/core'

export function customAlertEnter(AnimationC: Animation, baseEl: HTMLElement): Promise<Animation> {

    const baseAnimation = new AnimationC();

    const backdropAnimation = new AnimationC();
    backdropAnimation.addElement(baseEl.querySelector('ion-backdrop'));

    const wrapperAnimation = new AnimationC();
    const wrapperElem = baseEl.querySelector('.alert-wrapper') as HTMLElement;
    wrapperAnimation.addElement(wrapperElem);

    wrapperElem.style.top = '0';

    backdropAnimation.fromTo('opacity', 0.01, 0.3);

    wrapperAnimation.beforeStyles({ 'opacity': 1 });
    wrapperAnimation.fromTo('transform', `translateY(-${baseEl.clientHeight}px)`, 'translateY(0px)')

    return Promise.resolve(baseAnimation
      .addElement(baseEl)
      .easing('cubic-bezier(.36, .66, .3, .1, 1)')
      .duration(500)
      .add(wrapperAnimation)
      .add(backdropAnimation));
  }
```

and here is the code of `showAlert()`

```
  async showAlert(message: string){
    const alert = await this.toastController.create({
      message: message,
      duration: 2000,
      position: 'top',
      enterAnimation: customAlertEnter
    })
```

Thank you!